conditional probability of a function of dependent random variables
Assume $X$ and $Y$ are not independent random variables, and $F_{y}(x)$ is a cdf of $X$ given $Y = y$. I am confused, if the following is true. Assume we have measurable function $g$ and let us consider
$$
\mathbb P(X \leq g(Y)| Y = y)
$$
Would it be given by $F_{y}(g(y))$?
In general, if $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, do we always have for some $a$
$$
E[g(X,Y)< a|Y=y] = E[g(X,y)< a|Y=y] 
$$
?

What is causing your confusion? Given $Y=y$ then $g(Y)=g(y)$ and this is a number.

I added more to the question

$\mathbb P(X \leq g(Y)| Y = y)=\mathbb P(X \leq g(y))=F_X(g(y))$.

Dear van der Wolf, it is very not true. It is true only if $X$ and $Y$ are independent! There has to be CONDITIONAL cdf.
